# ERROR: gcloud crashed (TypeError): a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: docker, gcloud

I'm getting the above error after running the below docker command:

gcloud docker --verbosity=error -- push gcr.io/devtest/pipeline:2.0.1

Please help me!

This the Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b
Windows 10

Answer (score 5):

```
gcloud auth configure-docker
docker push gcr.io/devtest/pipeline:2.0.1
```

With the first command, you have already configured docker to use gcloud as the credential helper. Then you can just use docker as you would for any other registries.

Answer (score 3):

This particular use of the gcloud command is deprecated: gcloud docker is not supported for Docker client versions above 18.03. You may check for related information on the [gcloud docker](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/docker) documentation page.

At the end, in order to push the docker image into the registry with the latest version of gcloud and docker version 19.X the command will  be:

```
docker push gcr.io/<PROJECT_ID>/<PROJECT_NAME>:<TAG>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but `gcloud docker --authorize-only` also crashes with the same error.

I suspect this is related to python version incompatibilities.

Answer (score 0):

```
gcloud docker --authorize-only
docker push gcr.io/devtest/pipeline:2.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

gcloud components update --version 282.0.0

Comment: And what's that?

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.